# Lower throughput in a Bridge created as a Ethernet Switch in a Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ethernet, bridge

The setup is given below. I have a server with NIC(eth0 and eth1). I have created a bridge br0. The idea is I want to send the packets received from eth0 via br0 to eth1.

(Laptop)___________ Ubuntu Server___________(Laptop)

Iperf Server-----------eth0--br0--eth1-------------------Iperf client

the throughput at eth0 is 5 Gbps where as at eth1 I am receiving only 3 Gbps utmost.

I followed [this tutorial](https://chrisjhart.com/Bridge-Network-Interfaces-on-Ubuntu-22.04/) to create the network bridge.

STP is disabled in the bridge interface. I also disabled the packets to be sent over iptables for processing using this commands.

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, i found that pings through the bridge would fail while doing a speed test etc.

upping the mtu to 9000 fixed things for me, now ping latency barely changes while speedtest downloads at 500mbps, note in my case i only amended mtu br1 which is my inside interface, br0 is connected to a router that only does mtu of 1500 & upping interface mtu gives worse performance.

to see bridge interface mtu's

```
bridge link
```

```
chris@pcibridge-v2:~$ bridge link
2: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 2 
3: ens256: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 master br1 state forwarding priority 32 cost 2 
4: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 master br1 state forwarding priority 32 cost 4 
5: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
```

My netplan /etc/netplan/xxxxx.yml

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      mtu:  9000
      dhcp4:  no
    ens192:
      mtu:  1500
      dhcp4:  no
    ens224:
      mtu:  1500
      dhcp4:  no
    ens256:
      mtu:  9000
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4:  true
      interfaces:
        -  ens192
        -  ens224
    br1:
      dhcp4:  true
      interfaces:
        -  ens160
        -  ens256
  version: 2
```

I hope this helps